# Passing values between views php - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I have two views in Laravel, one is for 'denuncia' and the other is for 'map'. In 'denuncia' I get the location of the user, and what I want is to pass that value to the view 'map'.

Code for 'denuncia':

```js
@extends('layouts.master')
    
        @section('content')
    
            <h1>Denuncia</h1>
            <div class="table">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th><th>CI Denunciante</th><th>Tipo Denuncia</th>
        <th>Ubicacion</th><th>Ver Mapa</th><th>Cant.Vï¿½ctimas</th>
        <th>Estado</th><th>Servicio</th><th>Cant.Rodados</th>
        <th>Afectado</th><th>Agresiï¿½n F.</th><th>Menores</th>
        <th>Cant.Autores</th><th>Medio</th><th>Sexo</th>
        <th>Color-Pelo</th><th>Color-piel</th><th>Color-Ropa</th>
        <th>Vestimenta</th><th>Fecha</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    
        {{-- */$x=0;/* --}}
    
                    @foreach($denuncia as $item)
                        {{-- */$x++;/* --}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $item->id_denuncia }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->cuenta->ci }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->tipo->descripcion }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->ubicacion }}</td>
    
    <!--this is where I have to pass the value -->
        <td>
          <a href="{{ url('/map/' . $item->ubicacion ) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
        title="Ver Mapa">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"/></a>
        </td>
    
        <td>{{ $item->cant_victimas }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->estado_victimas }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->servicio }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->cant_rodados }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->afectado }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->agresion_fisica }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->menores }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->autores_cantidad }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->medio }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->sexo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->color_pelo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->color_piel }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->color_ropa }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->vestimenta }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->fecha }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="pagination"> {!! $denuncia->render() !!} </div>
            </div>
    
        @endsection
```

Code for Map (where I want to receive value from 'denuncia'):

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          #map { height: 100%; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>

    function initMap() {
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 4

      });

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
'</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    map: map,
    title: 'Location'
  });

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content : contentString});

  }
 </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code in my map controller to load the index page:

```
public function index()
    {
         $map = map::paginate(15);

        return view('map.index', compact('map'));

    }
```

I want to receive the value of location stored in 'denuncia' to put in the code above provided by google map and show it with a marker.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are these two views connected? You don't include one in the other as a partial or extending it?

Comment: Is there a way to just send that value to the map.php to use it? I've already send via url, like this: localhost:8000/map/-57.1145,-27.1452 but laravel makes a search for that value in the view map, because laravel understand this like a show by id.

Comment: Can you show how you load map.php?

Comment: Why not send the denunica location the way you send `$map` to the view?